# PHP saving variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables, submit

There is a `$variable`, its value is a big `Array()`.

It is created inside the `function one() { ... }` on the `first.php` page.

`first.php` has form with `method="post"`, after submition page reloads on `second.php`

Is there any way to get value of `$variable` inside `function two() { ... }` on the `second.php`?

Seems I can post value of `$variable` within form, the problem is it can contain more than thousand  symbols.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "[`session_start()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)" function at the very beginning of any PHP web page, just after the first PHP start tag (`<?php`).

Then store the variable of yours into a superglobal session array variable, in the "first.php" page like:-

```
<?php
session_start(); // This line must be at the very beginning of this PHP page.

function one() {
    // blah, blah, ...

    if(isset($variable) && !empty($variable)) {
        $_SESSION['customVariable'] = $variable;
    }

    // some more blah, blah, ...
}
?>
```

Now if you come to the "second.php" page, you need to access this page's function as:-

```
<?php
function two() {
    // if any blah, blah, ...

    if(isset($_SESSION['customVariable']) && !empty($_SESSION['customVariable'])) {
        $variable = $_SESSION['customVariable'];
    }

    // next series of blah, blah, ...
}
?>
```

But in this "second.php" page, the "`session_start()`" function must be written at the very beginning of this page just after the first PHP start tag.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for *Sessions*. Sessions allow the script to store user-specific data on server side without having to pass it through a form.

There is a full reference in the [Sessions book in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

There's a complete simple example on the [session_start() manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

Comment: @Ignatz then chances are you don't need session_start() at all: Just save your data into `$_SESSION`. To make sure you don't interfere with anything set by Wordpress, best prefix your variables with something unique, e.g. `$_SESSION["Ignatz_variablename"]` (you know what I mean) In future questions, make sure you *always* mention that you're in a  Wordpress project, it's almost always important.

Comment: You can only start sessions once. Wrap your `session_start()` in `if('' === session_id()){ session_start() }`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Simple example of usage is here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp